# SQL normalized data INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS ; ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

i am using MySql Workbench version 6.3.9 with mySql 5.6.35.

i have the following tables:

**EQUIPMENT**

eID | caochID | eName

**COACH**

coachID | coachName

SQLfiddle prepared http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e333d/1

eID is a primary key. there are multiple coachID's in different equipment, so there will be duplicate coachIDs with different equipment, but the eID will be unique as it is a primary key.

**REQUIRED**
i need to insert a row in the equipment table, if it does not already exist. If it exists, do nothing.

various posts online have pointed me towards two options:

a) INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...

b)INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS

**PROBLEM** i have problems with both of these solutions. for the first solution (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) the query inserts the row as required but does not update the existing row. instead it creates a new entry. for the second solution (WHERE NOT EXISTS) i get an error : SYNTAX ERROR: 'WHERE' (WHERE) is not a valid input at this position.

the sql query doesnt need to make any joins. i listed both tables so that you can see how they are related. the insert query i need will only insert for the equipment table.

Comment: so basically the `NOT EXISTS` should solve your OP but your query is generating errors.. why don't you post your `not exists` query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert by using a tmp table and ensuring that the same record is not existing from current table.  Add limit 1 to ensure only one record is inserted.    Below query will not insert since 1 and small ball exists.

```
INSERT INTO `Equipment` (`c_id`, `eName`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1', 'small ball') tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT c_id FROM Equipment WHERE `c_id`='1' and `eName` = 'small ball' 
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This was the right answer. thank you! just when i thought i had a firm grasp on SQL, it gets more in depth. i have a lot to learn. thanks again for the help.

Comment: glad to help; please accept the answer when you have time later.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS`

```
insert into table2 (....)  --- all if not columns ... destination
select ....
from table1 t1   --- source of data to check
where not exists (
select 1
from table2 t2
where t2.col = t1.col   --- match source and destination table making sure table1 data is not in table2
)
```

Comment: i dont need any links. i just need an insert query that will insert if it doesnt already exist. and if it exists, do nothing.

Comment: Have you got any idea what this insert would do?

Comment: @NishsBlemm obviously you don't need know how to use `not exists` ... the bottom query checks if table2 has the data of table1 otherwise do nothing

Comment: @maSTAShuFu sorry i think there was a misunderstanding... i should have explained myself better. but thanks for trying to help me. âńōŋŷXmoůŜ solution was the one that i was looking for.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i noticed that it involved the second table in the query. i just showed the second table to show the relationships...it wasnt necessary in the actual query. i feel i may have mislead the question by placing the second table there in the first place

Comment: @maSTAShuFu what do you mean?

Comment: @NishsBlemm your command originally started with "insert into table1", probably a typo that you corrected.